Infer function return type from parameter names dynamically
I have an external call untyped call that accepts a list of strings as input and return an object with this strings as keys. For example
const res = getAccount(['name', 'id']) will return an object of type { name: string, id: string}.
Is there a way to create a wrapper and make the call typesafe?
I tried with
type Obj<T extends string[]> = {
  [K in T[number]]: string;
};

that does the trick with non-dynamic parameters like type a = Obj<['id']>;

Something like this

Your wrapper function can look like this:
function getAccountWrapper<Name extends string>(
    names: readonly Name[]
): Record<Name, string> {
    return getAccount(names);
}

Some usage examples:
const res1 = getAccountWrapper(["name", "id"]);
//    ^? const res1: Record<"name" | "id", string>

const names2 = ["name", "id"] as const;
const res2 = getAccountWrapper(names2);
//    ^? const res2: Record<"name" | "id", string>

const names3 = ["name", "id"];
const res3 = getAccountWrapper(names3);
//    ^? const res3: Record<string, string>

Notice that only res1 and res2 have known keys. That's because TypeScript can infer them because it knows the string literal types of the elements at compile-time. But res3 is just Record<string, string> because the inferred type of names3 is just string[].
Playground link

Just to be clear, note that Record<"name" | "id", string> is { name: string; id: string; }, just in a different form. But you could also write the function type like this:
function getAccountWrapper<Name extends string>(
    names: readonly Name[]
): {[Key in Name]: string} {
    return getAccount(names);
}

// ...

// Usage:
const res1 = getAccountWrapper(["name", "id"]);
//    ^? const res1: { name: string; id: string; }

const names2 = ["name", "id"] as const;
const res2 = getAccountWrapper(names2);
//    ^? const res2: { name: string; id: string; }

const names3 = ["name", "id"];
const res3 = getAccountWrapper(names3);
//    ^? const res3: { [x: string]: string; }

Playground link

You could probably also just apply either of those function types to the existing getAccount function directly via a declaration file, but the specifics depend on how and where you get getAccount.
